# Plotly xaxis in weekday name

Tags: python, plotly

I’ve looked into the documentation but they didn’t seem to mention it.

https://plot.ly/python/axes/

How can I change the label on x axis to show “Mon 20-7”, “Tue 21-7”, etc. 
The 'date' used for xaxis is in the format "20-7-2018 11:00:00am", etc.

I use the following Python Plotly script:

```
trace0=go.Scatter(x=df_pre.index,y=df_pre['Total'],line=dict(color=('rgb(16,25,109)'),width=1),name='Period_1')

trace1=go.Scatter(x=df_post.index,y=df_post['Total'],line=dict(color=('rgb(77,221,26)'),width=2),name='Period_2')

data=[trace0,trace1]

layout=dict(title='Total',width=960,height=768,
              yaxis=dict(title='Avg',ticklen=5,zeroline=False,gridwidth=2,),
              xaxis=dict(title='Date',ticklen=5,zeroline=False,gridwidth= 2,))

fig=dict(data=data,layout=layout)

iplot(fig,filename='Total')
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to see "Tue 14-08" on xaxis, follow those steps(added in code below):

1.Create a column which corresponds to your requirements

```
df_pre["date2"] = df_pre["date"].apply(lambda x: datetime.datetime.\
                strptime(x,"%d-%m-%Y %I:%M:%S%p").strftime("%a %d-%m"))
print(df_pre["date2"])
0    Tue 14-08
1    Wed 15-08
2    Thu 16-08
3    Fri 17-08
4    Sat 18-08
Name: date2, dtype: object
```

2.Create a list called 'list_' from column that looks like you want to see it on xaxis (`df_pre["date2"]`)

```
list_ = df_pre["date2"].tolist()
print(list_)
['Tue 14-08', 'Wed 15-08', 'Thu 16-08', 'Fri 17-08', 'Sat 18-08']
```

3.Put in xaxis `Layout` two parameters `tickvals` and `ticktext`: in  first parameter over how many values you want to iterate. And in second parameter choose you text (such as `list_` that we get from column `df["date2"]`)

```
layout=dict(title="Total",width=960,height=768,
            yaxis=dict(title="Avg",ticklen=5,zeroline=False,gridwidth=2),
            xaxis=dict(title="Date",ticklen=5,zeroline=False,gridwidth=2,
                       #Choose what you want to see on xaxis! In this case list_
                       tickvals=[i for i in range(len(list_))],
                       ticktext=list_
                       ))
```

And the output should be something like this:
[image: It is exactly what you want, yep?]

I am can not find the option in documentation, that your need. But do not forgot, you can prepare data that you after can put in `x`, using `Python` and `pandas`:

```
#Import all what we need
import pandas as pd
import plotly
import plotly.graph_objs as go
#Create first DataFrame
df_pre = pd.DataFrame({"date":["14-08-2018 11:00:00am",
                               "15-08-2018 12:00:00am",
                               "16-08-2018 01:00:00pm",
                               "17-08-2018 02:00:00pm",
                               "18-08-2018 03:00:00pm"],
                       "number":["3","5","10","18","22"]})
#Create a column which corresponds to your requirements
df_pre["dow"] = pd.to_datetime(df_pre["date"], \
                               format="%d-%m-%Y %I:%M:%S%p").dt.weekday_name
df_pre["firstchunk"] = df_pre["dow"].astype(str).str[0:3]
df_pre["lastchunk"] = df_pre["date"].astype(str).str[0:5]
df_pre["final"] = df_pre["firstchunk"] + " " + df_pre["lastchunk"]
#Check DataFrame
print(df_pre)
#Repeat all the actions above to the second DataFrame
df_post = pd.DataFrame({"date":["14-08-2018 11:00:00am",
                                "15-08-2018 12:00:00am",
                                "16-08-2018 01:00:00pm",
                                "17-08-2018 02:00:00pm",
                                "18-08-2018 03:00:00pm"],
                        "number":["6","8","12","19","23"]})
df_post["dow"] = pd.to_datetime(df_post["date"], \
                                format="%d-%m-%Y %I:%M:%S%p").dt.weekday_name
df_post["firstchunk"] = df_post["dow"].astype(str).str[0:3]
df_post["lastchunk"] = df_post["date"].astype(str).str[0:5]
df_post["final"] = df_post["firstchunk"] + " " + df_post["lastchunk"]
print(df_post)
#Create list needed for xaxis
list_ = df_pre["final"].tolist()
print(list_)
#Prepare data
trace0=go.Scatter(x=df_pre["date"],y=df_pre["number"],
                  line=dict(color=("rgb(16,25,109)"),width=1),name="Period_1")
trace1=go.Scatter(x=df_post["date"],y=df_post["number"],
                  line=dict(color=("rgb(77,221,26)"),width=2),name="Period_2")
data = [trace0,trace1]
#Prepare layout
layout=dict(title="Total",width=960,height=768,
            yaxis=dict(title="Avg",ticklen=5,zeroline=False,gridwidth=2),
            xaxis=dict(title="Date",ticklen=5,zeroline=False,gridwidth=2,
                       #Choose what you want to see on xaxis! In this case list_
                       tickvals=[i for i in range(len(list_))],
                       ticktext=list_
                       ))
fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)
#Save plot as "Total.html" in directory where your script is
plotly.offline.plot(fig, filename="Total.html", auto_open = False)
```

**Update:** Also you can try using `datetime` to achieve what you want (that`s more simple):

```
#Import all what we need
import pandas as pd
import plotly
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import datetime
#Create first DataFrame
df_pre = pd.DataFrame({"date":["14-08-2018 11:00:00am",
                               "15-08-2018 12:00:00am",
                               "16-08-2018 01:00:00pm",
                               "17-08-2018 02:00:00pm",
                               "18-08-2018 03:00:00pm"],
                       "number":["3","5","10","18","22"]})
#Create a column which corresponds to your requirements
df_pre["date2"] = df_pre["date"].apply(lambda x: datetime.datetime.\
            strptime(x,"%d-%m-%Y %I:%M:%S%p").strftime("%a %d-%m"))
#Check DataFrame
print(df_pre)
#Repeat all the actions above to the second DataFrame
df_post = pd.DataFrame({"date":["14-08-2018 11:00:00am",
                                "15-08-2018 12:00:00am",
                                "16-08-2018 01:00:00pm",
                                "17-08-2018 02:00:00pm",
                                "18-08-2018 03:00:00pm"],
                        "number":["6","8","12","19","23"]})
df_post["date2"] = df_post["date"].apply(lambda x: datetime.datetime.\
             strptime(x,'%d-%m-%Y %I:%M:%S%p').strftime("%a %d-%m"))
print(df_post)
#Create list that needed to xaxis
list_ = df_pre["date2"].tolist()
print(list_)
#Prepare data
trace0=go.Scatter(x=df_pre["date"],y=df_pre["number"],
                  line=dict(color=("rgb(16,25,109)"),width=1),name="Period_1")
trace1=go.Scatter(x=df_post["date"],y=df_post["number"],
                  line=dict(color=("rgb(77,221,26)"),width=2),name="Period_2")
data = [trace0,trace1]
#Prepare layout
layout=dict(title="Total",width=960,height=768,
            yaxis=dict(title="Avg",ticklen=5,zeroline=False,gridwidth=2),
            xaxis=dict(title="Date",ticklen=5,zeroline=False,gridwidth=2,
                       #Choose what you want to see on xaxis! In this case list_
                       tickvals=[i for i in range(len(list_))],
                       ticktext=list_
                       ))
fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)
#Save plot as "Total.html" in directory where your script is
plotly.offline.plot(fig, filename="Total.html")
```

Comment: Hi Oysiyl, now that the date column is in string. When I convert it to a datetime object, the weekday name is gone. I need to convert into datetime object so that I can do time shift. How can I retain the format 'Tue 14-08' but the dtype is a time object?

Comment: @Marlin, I tried to solve your problem today but did not succeed. Sorry=( Maybe someone else can help you. I see one possible solution for now: made time shift with datetime which looking like (2018-08-14). And then, after calculations format this date column again to string look  like (Tue 08-14).

Comment: @ Oysisyl, I got it. Your suggestion above works!!! My only question now is that the x axis in the plot shows 'Fri 20-07 03:00:00'. Is there any chance we can get rid of the time part in the plot display? I cannot remove the time in data because that will remove the number of data points.

Comment: @Marlin, you can create list such as `df["date"].tolist()`. Then split that using `.str.split(" ")[0:2]` (and choose first three chunks). You should get what you want as elements in a list. And send this list as a `x` in `trace`. Ohh, that is change the number of data points. How your plot looks like? You have couple of points on each `day` or why time part is important in your case? Look at `ticktext` and `tickvals` [here](https://plot.ly/python/axes/). Maybe you can customize xaxis using those `ticks`

Comment: @Marlin, check updated answer. I hope that solve your problem=)

Comment: @ Oysisyl, thanks so much.. Yes, your response solved my problem. Much appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

you can do like this :-

```
data = [go.Scatter(x=df.Date, y=df.High)]
```

for more reference, you could refer this link :-
https://plot.ly/python/time-series/

Happy Learning!

Comment: He had done this in code and couldn't be able to resolve, thats why he asks for a new method of doing this.